# 3 laptops and 2 tablets from Chicago to Chennai

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens

I have a total of 3 laptops and 2 tablets to take in my carry on and/or laptop bag.

One laptop is my work laptop.
The second laptop is personal which is 3 years old.
The third one is also personal but it is damaged very badly with taping all over. It is more than 5 years old, and looks in bad condition.

The 2 tablets are each worth $50 each and are new.

How should I carry these? Will I have a problem taking all of these on the plane?

Comment: no problem whatsoever, i often travel with that many laptops and pads. if you are asking about CUSTOMS, who knows - they may charge you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can convince the customs officials that there is no commercial purpose, you will be able to bring them just fine.

For your broken laptop, note that you will probably have problems taking it over customs because as far as I know, your laptop must be in working condition. See more from [here](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/01/09/us-customs-can-and-will-seize-laptops-and-cellphones-demand-passwords/).

In Chennai, you can explain the officials (Tamil/English) that you are using one for your work, and the other one is already a used one. A couple of tabs is usually OK. You have up to 45,000 INR allowance ([link](http://www.immihelp.com/travel-to-india/baggage-allowance-rules/indian-residents.html)) for short stays.